# Continuous function on a locally compact space attains maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Currently I am reading [Isometries on Banach Spaces - Vector-valued Function Spaces and Operator Spaces, Volume Two](https://www.crcpress.com/Isometries-in-Banach-Spaces-Vector-valued-Function-Spaces-and-Operator/Fleming-Jamison/p/book/9781584883869).

Notation: $K$ is a locally compact space, $X$ is a Banach space and $C_0(K,X)$ is a space of continuous functions from $K$ to $X$ which vanish at infinity.

For any function $F\in C_0(K,X),$ its supremum norm is denoted by $\|F\| = \sup_{k\in K}\| F(k)\|.$

In page $4,$ the authors stated the following:

> For each $F\in C_0(K,X),$ let $K_F = \{ k\in K:\|F(k)\|=\|F\| \}.$ Then $K_F$ is closed and **nonempty**.

**Question:** Why is the set $K_F$ nonempty? We know that $F$ is a continuous function on a locally compact space which vanishes at infinity. But does this guarantee that $F$ must attain its maximum at some point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed.

If $F$ is identically zero, there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, we may find a compact set $S \subset K$ such that $\|F(s)\| \le \|F\|/2$ holds for all $s\in S^c$ (since $F$ vanishes at infinity). But this means that the maximum of $F$ on $S$ is also the global maximum of $F$. Since $S$ is a compact set and $F$ is continuous, it attains it maximum on $S$ and thus its global maximum.

Comment: What is your definition of a function vanishing st infinity?

Comment: The definition I used says that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a compact set $K$ such that $\|f(k)\| \le \varepsilon$ holds for all $k \in K^c$.